# Name scope for memoization Fibonacci

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, fibonacci-sequence

Here's a snippet of code I use to examine the functionality of Python decorator(`@memorize`). An example of Fibonacci computation:

```
def memorize(f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(*args):
        if args not in memo:
            memo[args] = f(*args)
        return memo[args]
    return helper

def fib(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    elif n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

**Here's the problem:**

Different naming is causing a huge speed difference, why is it?

- Execution 1:

  ```
  s = time.time()
  fib = memorize(fib)
  a = fib(40)
  e = time.time()
  print(a)
  print(e-s)
  ```

  returns

  > 102334155
  >
  > 7.319450378417969e-05
- Execution 2:

  ```
  s = time.time()
  memo_fib = memorize(fib)
  a = memo_fib(40)
  e = time.time()
  print(a)
  print(e-s)
  ```

  returns

  > 102334155
  >
  > 46.79982662200928

**Edited:**

A screen copy from running the code
[image]

**Edited:**

Unless running the two executions seperately, to obtain aforementioned results, "Execution 2" must be run before "Execution 1".

Comment: I can't reproduce your reported timing results. Can you double-check your work, please?

Comment: Got it double checked and attached with a screenshot, still couldn't figure out where it goes wrong. @GarethRees

Comment: Aha, you have to do execution 2 before execution 1. That wasn't clear from your original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fib` works by recursively calling the function named `fib`:

```
def fib(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    elif n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

In your "execution 1" the function named `fib` is the memoized version of the function, because you have assigned it like this:

```
fib = memorize(fib)
```

But (assuming that you haven't run "execution 1" yet), in your "execution 2" the function named `fib` is the original function (not the memoized version of the function, which you have assigned to `memo_fib`), so when you call `memo_fib` it calls the original `fib` and when that recurses it calls the original `fib`, bypassing the memoization.